# N-D interpolation for equally-spaced data

Tags: numpy, scipy

I'm trying to copy the Scipy Cookbook function:

```
from scipy import ogrid, sin, mgrid, ndimage, array
x,y = ogrid[-1:1:5j,-1:1:5j]
fvals = sin(x)*sin(y)
newx,newy = mgrid[-1:1:100j,-1:1:100j]
x0 = x[0,0]
y0 = y[0,0]
dx = x[1,0] - x0
dy = y[0,1] - y0
ivals = (newx - x0)/dx
jvals = (newy - y0)/dy
coords = array([ivals, jvals])
newf = ndimage.map_coordinates(fvals, coords)
```

by using my own function that has to work for many scenarios

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
"""N-D interpolation for equally-spaced data"""                                         
x = np.c_[plist['modx']]                                                                
y = np.transpose(np.c_[plist['mody']])                                                  
pdb.set_trace()                                                                         
#newx,newy = np.meshgrid(plist['newx'],plist['newy'])                                   
newx,newy = scipy.mgrid[plist['modx'][0]:plist['modx'][-1]:-plist['remapto'],               
                     plist['mody'][0]:plist['mody'][-1]:-plist['remapto']]                                                                                        
x0 = x[0,0]                                                                             
y0 = y[0,0]                                                                             
dx = x[1,0] - x0                                                                        
dy = y[0,1] - y0                                                                        
ivals = (newx - x0)/dx                                                                  
jvals = (newy - y0)/dy                                                                  
coords = scipy.array([ivals, jvals])                                                    
for i in np.arange(ivals.shape[0]):                                                     
    nvals[i] = scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates(ivals[i], coords)
```

I'm having difficulty getting this code to work properly. The problem areas are: 
1.) Recreating this line: newx,newy = mgrid[-1:1:100j,-1:1:100j]. In my case I have a dictionary with the grid in vector form.  I've tried to recreate this line using np.meshgrid but then I get an error on line coords = scipy.array([ivals, jvals]). I'm looking for some help in recreating this Cookbook function and making it more dynamic
any help is greatly appreciated.

/M

Comment: What do you mean when you say the grid is in "vector" form? Can you post a sample of the array?

Comment: Sorry about that. What I mean by vector is a 1D array. E.g.,                       plist['modx']=array([10.125,9.,7.875,6.75,5.625,4.5,3.375,2.25,1.125,-0.,-1.125,-2.25,-3.375,-4.5,-5.625,-6.75,-7.875,-9.,-10.125])
plist['mody']
array([ 10.125,9.,7.875,6.75,5.625,4.5,3.375,2.25,1.125,-0.,-1.125,-2.25,-3.375,-4.5,-5.625,-6.75,-7.875,-9.,-10.125])
plist['remapto']
0.703125
The input ivals has the dimension (19,19). The function is suppose to increase the resolution from 1.125 to 0.703125.

Comment: What error are you getting from the current code?

Comment: Also, your current code example is not valid python. You have a `return` statement that is not inside of a function.

Comment: "invalid shape for coordinate array" for current form. I have to rearrange it a to get the error with np.meshgrid. Will post it soon.

Comment: The same error for np.meshgrid: "invalid shape for coordinate array".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the documentation for [`map_coordinates`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html). I don't see where the actual data you are trying to interpolate is in your code. What I mean is, presumably you have some data `input` which is a function of `x` and `y`; i.e. `input = f(x,y)` that you want to interpolate. In the first example you show, this is the array `fvals`. This should be your first argument to `map_coordinates`.

For example, if the data you are trying to inperpolate is `input`, which should be a 2-dimensional array of shape `(len(x),len(y))`, then the interpolated data would be:

```
interpolated_data = map_coordinates(input, coords)
```

Comment: ivals is a 2D array (19,19) and coords has the new shape but is 3D: (2,31,31). The cookbook example works but I keep getting an error from coords.

Comment: I still cannot get this interpolation to work. After reading up about map_coordinates and rewriting the function I get results that is wrong. The data is garbled and displaced. Is this 2D bilinear interpolation possible in scipy?

Comment: Please edit your question and post your updated code, preferably with small example arrays and then post what you expected, and what you got.

Comment: Map_coordinates resulted in results that were incorrect and somewhat garbled. A solution that worked uses griddata. Here's the meat of it:
    lats = plist['xlats'];lons = plist['xlons'];
    lat_old, lon_old = np.meshgrid(lats,lons)                                                     
    lon_new = plist['newx']+lon;lat_new = plist['newy']+lat
    lat_new = lat_new[::-1]                             
    nvals[i] = matplotlib.mlab.griddata(lat_old.flatten(),                                    
    lon_old.flatten(),ivals[i].flatten(),lat_new,lon_new)